# Qlik Sense Sum of One field based on unique value of other fields

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

Sample Data:

```
    P   Q    R
    1   A    3
    1   A    3
    1   A    2
    1   B    5
    1   C    7
    2   A    3
    2   A    3
```

Expected Output:

```
P   Q    R
1   A    5
1   B    5
1   C    7
2   A    3
```

i Have tried this Sum (Distinct R) but it is not working. i need to group by P and Q column and add Unique Value of R for that. Please support

Comment: this to be solved in the script or in chart? if "chart" then what are the planned dimensions? only "P"?

Comment: chart and only P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chart, you have to add P and Q fields as dimensions. Then your expression should work just fine.

In script your code should look like this:

```
Load P, Q, Sum( Distinct R ) as sum_of_R
FROM sample_data
Group By P, Q;
```